# Any available Travel Dataset

Tags: data-request

We are looking for travel dataset which would contain details of destinations, activities, user ratings etc. on which text summarization and recommendation can be performed and evaluated.

Answer (score 3):

The University of Illinois has an archived dataset of tripadviser reviews for up thru 2008.

http://times.cs.uiuc.edu/~wang296/Data/

TripAdvisor also has an API. I've never used it so I don't know the terms of use:

http://api-portal.anypoint.mulesoft.com/tripadvisor/api/tripadvisor-api

The UK government publishes annual travel surverys, starting from 2007. This data is at the region level, how many visitors, how many miles traveled, etc.

http://data.gov.uk/dataset/national_travel_survey

Comment: Thank you. The TripAdvisor reviews dataset has reviews available only for hotels. The API requires verification of the website or app, where as we are looking data for research purposes.

Answer (score 1):

http://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwikivoyage contains the wiki dump of Wiki Voyage pages of different places. XML parser can be used to get the individual files from the xml dump. This can server as set of pages for the summarization module.